# How to enforce ajax of jquery to wait before executing the following statement

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple codesample to do two things:

- inquire the accept lang header (ajax)
- use/reference it (can be part of ajax, since that need be in many places, the sample is to display on the screen.)

The html is like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<H1 id=bLocale>Should be the browser locale here</H1>
</body>
<script>
var bLocale='unchanged';
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://ajaxhttpheaders.appspot.com", 
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    success: function(headers) {
        bLocale= headers['Accept-Language'];
        comma=bLocale.indexOf(',');
        if(comma>0) bLocale=bLocale.substring(0, comma);
    },
    async:   false
});
$("#bLocale").text(bLocale);
</script>
</html>
```

The problem is that ajax is too slow (even with asyn set false) and the display happens before bLocale gets the returned value.

Any idea to address this issue?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: Not with JSONP, no. JSONP is by nature async. True ajax alls can be forced to be synchronous, but not JSONP.

Comment: Why aren't you not just putting `$("#bLocale").text(bLocale);` inside your AJAX success function

Comment: You can't use `async: false` with jsonp, nor should you *ever* use it anyway.  Put `$("#bLocale").text(bLocale);` inside the `success` function.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that ajax is too slow (even with asyn set false) and the display happens before bLocale gets the returned value.

You're telling jQuery to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), which is inherently asynchronous; `async: false` has no effect on it. `async: false` works on *true* ajax requests, but not JSONP. (It won't for a lot longer, though; the jQuery team are removing the `async` option and you'd have to use `XMLHttpRequest` directly to get a synchronous request.)

Moreover, you don't *want* a synchronous request. Embrace the asynchronous, event-driven nature of web development:

```
var bLocale='unchanged'; // Move this *into* the success function unless
                         // you really, really need it to be outside it
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://ajaxhttpheaders.appspot.com", 
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    success: function(headers) {
        bLocale= headers['Accept-Language'];
        comma=bLocale.indexOf(',');
        if(comma>0) bLocale=bLocale.substring(0, comma);

        $("#bLocale").text(bLocale);  // <=== Inside the callback, not outside it
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, embedding the display code would work for this sample code, but in reality I need bLocale in many places, so I need to know it gets the right value.  In that case, will changing to another data type enforce synchornous?

Comment: some times you cant see the forest for trees. So obvious, does it every day, forgetting other people might not.

Comment: @user3097579: It doesn't matter that you need it in a lot of places. You set it up so that you tell the other places that the information is ready (from within the callback). *"will changing to another data type enforce synchornous"* It would if it worked, but my guess is you're using JSONP for a reason (specifically, to work around Same Origin Policy issues). JSONP is probably the right choice for that. Your only other option is CORS, but that relies on the service you're using supporting it, the browser your visitor is using supporting it, and you need a special plug-in to support older IE.

Comment: @user3097579: For completeness: CORS = [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). But again, it's not really likely you can use it here.

Comment: Thanks, T.J. Crowder.  The difficulty is that this is the environment set up, and we don't know when the other parts need it.  I hope that jQuery or even HTTP designers listen to this.  Giving a multithreading environment with no syncronization mechanism will definitely cause troubles.

Comment: I changed url to http://ajaxhttpheaders.appspot.com?callback=headers, which returns the entire headers if directly posting it on the browser, and set datatype to text, but the jquery throws error: [Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: file:///C:/jquery_tester/jquery-1.11.0.js :: .send :: line 9666" data: no]  Is this due to SOP?

Comment: @user3097579: *"Giving a multithreading environment with no syncronization mechanism will definitely cause troubles"* JavaScript on web browsers is single-threaded unless you use web workers, and if you use web workers, the only cross-thread communication is via message posting. This has nothing to do with multi-threading. With proper design, a system can embrace asynchronicity and benefit from it. Re JSONP: There's nothing the jQuery people can do about its asynchronous nature, that's just how it is, full stop.

Answer (score 0):

`It's right that it's impossible to use ajax to achieve synchronization.  As the return is jsonp, we can load it in a script tag.  See the following.  Thanks for all the help that prompts me to this solution.`

`<html>`
`<head>`
`<script>`

```
var bLocale='raw'; // can be used at any other place

function processHeaders(headers){
    bLocale=headers['Accept-Language'];
    comma=bLocale.indexOf(',');
    if(comma>0) bLocale=bLocale.substring(0, comma);
}
```

`</script>`

`<script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>`

`<script type="application/javascript" src="http://ajaxhttpheaders.appspot.com?callback=processHeaders"></script>`

`</head>`
`<body>`

`<H1 id=bLocale>Should be the browser locale here</H1>`

`</body>`

`<script>`

```
$("#bLocale").text(bLocale);
```

`</script>`
`</html>`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get IE working.  Any workarounds?